# How is estimated degree of freedom in GAM determined?

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

I was working on my GAM model:

```
y <- c(0.0000943615,0.0074918919,0.0157332851,0.0783308615,
       0.1546375803,0.5558444681,0.8583806898,0.9617216854,
       0.9848004112,0.9964662546)
x <- log(c(0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.4, 0.8, 1.6, 3.2, 4.5, 6.4))

fit.gam <- mgcv::gam(y ~ s(x,k=-1, bs="cr"))

summary(fit.gam)
coef(fit.gam)
```

The model summary tells me that the edf of s(x) is 6.893 with p-value = 0.0017:

```
> summary(fit.gam)

Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
y ~ s(x, k = -1, bs = "cr")

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.46135    0.00629   73.34 0.000126 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
       edf Ref.df     F p-value   
s(x) 6.893  7.902 585.7  0.0017 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.998   Deviance explained =  100%
GCV = 0.0018783  Scale est. = 0.0003957  n = 10
```

The coefficients of my model still contain 9 coefficients for s(x).

```
> coef(fit.gam)
(Intercept)      s(x).1      s(x).2      s(x).3      s(x).4      s(x).5      s(x).6 
  0.4613501  -0.3450787  -0.3229509  -0.2895761  -0.1783854   0.1976228   0.5040469 
     s(x).7      s(x).8      s(x).9 
  0.6135856   0.6338979   0.6470116
```

My question is I understand that GAM penalized the variable x in some extent so that the estimated degree of freedom of x = 6.893 < 9, but from the coefficients of s(x), it is hard for me to tell which basis is penalized. How should I understand the relationship between edf and coefficients of s(x)? Thanks!

Comment: You should get the book that supports the `mgcv` package (or find a copy online) and read up on it. The table of contents includes  "3.2.2 Controlling the degree of smoothing with penalized regression splines" starting on page 126. This isn't really a coding question and would require more than a short answer. You should search for the answer on CrossValidated.com and if no answer there already then request migration since it's probably on-topic there.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=estimated+degree+of+freedom+in+GAM+

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @IRTFM. I should check the book more carefully to see how things work out. I also searched the cross-validation, there is not a specific question that solves my concern. I decide to double-check the book first then see whether I should move the question to CrossValidation. Thank you!